# Unable to start Docker service with error "Failed to start docker.service: Unit not found."

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I have installed Docker with `yum install docker`:

```
$ uname -a
Linux caspgval4 3.10.0-229.20.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Nov 4 10:08:36 CST 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ docker --version
Docker version 1.12.6, build 3a094bd/1.12.6

$ docker info
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?

$ sudo systemctl status docker
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: http://docs.docker.com
```

I am trying to install and run Docker, but it is giving an error as below:

```
$ sudo service docker start
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start  docker.service
Failed to start docker.service: Unit not found.
```

How do I resolve this issue? I tried the following commands, but no luck:

```
$ sudo systemctl start docker
Failed to start docker.service: Unit not found.
```

Extra information:

```
$ journalctl -u docker
No journal files were found.
-- No entries --

$ cat /usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service
[Unit]
Description=Docker Application Container Engine
Documentation=http://docs.docker.com
After=network.target
Wants=docker-storage-setup.service
Requires=rhel-push-plugin.socket
Requires=docker-cleanup.timer

[Service]
Type=notify
NotifyAccess=all
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/docker
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/docker-storage
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/docker-network
Environment=GOTRACEBACK=crash
Environment=DOCKER_HTTP_HOST_COMPAT=1
Environment=PATH=/usr/libexec/docker:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd-current \
          --add-runtime docker-runc=/usr/libexec/docker/docker-runc-current \
          --default-runtime=docker-runc \
          --authorization-plugin=rhel-push-plugin \
          --exec-opt native.cgroupdriver=systemd \
          --userland-proxy-path=/usr/libexec/docker/docker-proxy-current \
          $OPTIONS \
          $DOCKER_STORAGE_OPTIONS \
          $DOCKER_NETWORK_OPTIONS \
          $ADD_REGISTRY \
          $BLOCK_REGISTRY \
          $INSECURE_REGISTRY
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
LimitNOFILE=1048576
LimitNPROC=1048576
LimitCORE=infinity
TimeoutStartSec=0
Restart=on-abnormal
MountFlags=slave

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I tried the following:

```
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
$ sudo systemctl start docker
Failed to start docker.service: Unit not found.
$ sudo journalctl -u docker
-- No entries --
```

More debug information:

```
$ sudo systemctl status network.target
● network.target - Network
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/network.target; static; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active since Mon 2017-01-23 02:54:39 PST; 2 months 29 days ago
     Docs: man:systemd.special(7)
           http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/NetworkTarget

Jan 23 02:54:39 mymachine systemd[1]: Starting Network.
Jan 23 02:54:39 mymachine systemd[1]: Reached target Network.

$ sudo systemctl status docker-storage-setup.service
● docker-storage-setup.service - Docker Storage Setup
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker-storage-setup.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)

$ sudo systemctl status rhel-push-plugin.socket
Unit rhel-push-plugin.socket could not be found.

$ sudo systemctl status docker-cleanup.timer
● docker-cleanup.timer - Run docker-cleanup every hour
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker-cleanup.timer; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

Comment: Have you run `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`? If not, please do so and retry the `sudo systemctl start docker` and `sudo journalctl -u docker` if there are any errors.

Comment: Tried and updated the same in the question.

Comment: Check your other dependent units with a `sudo systemctl status $x` for network.target, docker-storage-setup.service, rhel-push-plugin.socket, and docker-cleanup.timer.

Comment: Updated above details in the question.

Comment: If there is any chance you installed `docker-latest` that would be, what blocked me.

Answer (score 83):

Run this command to list all the services:

```
sudo systemctl list-units --type=service
```

Look for the correct Docker service name (in my case it is `snap.docker.dockerd.service`) then run:

```
sudo systemctl restart snap.docker.dockerd.service
```

Comment: I don't know why this solution has a low rating. Works for me. Cheers

Comment: Worked for me! Mine was just called `docker` rather than `dockerd` (what I was originally trying)

Comment: This deserves higher rating indeed

Comment: `sudo systemctl list-units --type=service | grep "docker"` will display only results with docker.

Comment: when i run @RubyRube command to narrow down the list is empty and when i run your command @iNSiDER it showed this 
`Failed to restart snap.docker.dockerd.service: Unit snap.docker.dockerd.service not found.`
i had docker installed but i haven't used it for a while and when i tried to start it wont open properly .. the docker cli says the docker engine has stopped and when i go to the setting its on infinite loading.

Answer (score 42):

In case someone has installed docker using snap, they can start the service using

```sh
sudo snap status docker #check the status
sudo snap start docker # start the service
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Thanks Amarjit!

Comment: for the first command it says - error: unknown command "status", see 'snap help'.

Comment: this command works in ubuntu 20 LTS: sudo snap start docker # start the service

Comment: @LuisEstrada is there any command to check Docker status in 22.04.1 LTS

Comment: @deltanboi same as above: sudo snap status docker

Comment: error: unknown command "status", see 'snap help'.

Answer (score 41):

It looks like you're missing the rhel-push-plugin.socket unit which is presumably part of a rhel-push-plugin package. You can try fixing that install, or you can install the upstream Docker package directly from Docker with the following as root:

```
curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh
```

Or more appropriately following the [CentOS install guide from Docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/centos/). (The CentOS install tends to work on even a RHEL system when you have a supported version, which until the recent 20.10 release did not include CentOS 8 or RHEL 8.)

The upstream Docker install will be a more recent version of Docker, but it will not have the various RHEL modifications like the rhel-push-plugin.

Answer (score 32):

Use the following command if your OS is Ubuntu, it will install Docker successfully:

```
apt install docker.io
```

Comment: Installed with this command however docker.service is still not running.

Comment: After wasting almost a day, this worked for me. Thanks for this. I think part of the issue is that I was using the Docker Desktop in Ubuntu.

Comment: worked for me, had to add sudo though

Answer (score 8):

Try to run this command -
`sudo apt-get install containerd.io docker-ce`

It will install containerd runtime and some dependencies for docker.service

Then try to run - `sudo systemctl list-units --type=service | grep "docker"` 
You will see docker.service is available

then check status- `sudo service docker status`

And you're good to go!

Comment: Hi @TábataBaesso Glad you help! In some cases of Docker Desktop `Containerd` is not installed that's why these steps are mandatory :)

Comment: I've been stuck on this issue for months thanks you are a star

Answer (score 7):

if you have installed docker with snap you can check the status of the daemon like this:

```
sudo snap services docker
```

If the `current` column shows `inactive` then it's not running. Try starting it with this:

```
sudo snap start docker
```

Check the service again, if it's still not running after that you can check the logs:

```
sudo snap logs docker
```

which might give more hints on what's stopping it from running

For me, I had an error saying that docker could not create a symlink in `/etc/docker/` because another file was in the way. Emptying the directory was not enough due to a known bug in the docker snap. The work-around was to delete the directory then refresh the snap  (see https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/layouts-still-brittle-when-refreshing-snaps/26252/2)

```
sudo rm -rf /etc/docker
sudo snap refresh
```

Answer (score 1):

I worked around the issue by simply doing the following:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge containerd.io docker-ce
$ rm -rf /var/lib/containerd
[reboot]
$ sudo apt-get install containerd.io docker-ce
```

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu, the following command works for me:

> sudo apt install docker.io

Comment: Please explain why this will help. Also, please read [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: This saved my life! In Ubunto, this the command you need to install Docker.

Answer (score -1):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/docker-basics.html

Note

In some cases, you may need to reboot your instance to provide permissions for the ec2-user to access the Docker daemon. Try rebooting your instance if you see the following error:

Answer (score -5):

Try installing Docker as root (sudo):

```
sudo yum install docker
```

See *[Installation on Red Hat Enterprise Linux](https://docs.docker.com/v1.11/engine/installation/linux/rhel/)*.

Comment: It was installed with root only.