# Why can't run docker compose commands on docker v4.x.x?

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, centos

I am working on a remote server which has centOS version `VERSION="8.7 (Green Obsidian)"`.It was installed docker previously by another developer. The docker version was likely 4.x.x.In my docker-compose.yaml file I used `version:'3'` In this version, docker basic commands like `docker ps, docker images` etc. worked well. Then I installed docker-compose using

```
sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/latest/download/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
docker-compose version
```

Then it was installed `Docker Compose version v2.18.1` , Now I tried to run docker compose commands,it says `can not connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?`. Then tried to enable and start docker service,using

```
    systemctl status docker
    /usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)

    sudo systemctl start docker
     systemd([l]: docker.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
     systemd[l]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
     systemd[l]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
    1:48:40  systemd[l]: docker.service: Service RestartSec=2s expired, scheduling restart.
    Jun as 11:48:40  systemd[l]: docker.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 3.
    Jun 09 11:4 0  systemd[l]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
    Jun 09 11:48:40  systemd[l]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
    Jun 09 11:48:40  systemd[l]: docker.service: Failed with result ‘'exit-code’. I
    Jun 09 11:48:40  systemd[l]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
```

I try to find docker.service, docker.sock,containerd.service files in system folder, they were not available. Then i referred [Unable to start Docker service with error "Failed to start docker.service: Unit not found."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43569781/unable-to-start-docker-service-with-error-failed-to-start-docker-service-unit) and created docker.service manually. Then, referred [Cannot start docker daemon in CentOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42217526/cannot-start-docker-daemon-in-centos7) and created docker.socket file. But could not find content for containerd.service file. Then also could not start docker service using `sudo systemctl start docker`. Can I know whether it is a good idea to upgrade docker version 4.x.x to latest 23 instead of bothering about missing files and manually creating these missing files?. This [official docker site](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/centos/#install-using-the-repository) shows the upgrading method as follows,

```
sudo yum install /path/to/package.rpm
sudo systemctl start docker
sudo docker run hello-world
yum -y upgrade
```